# Reference request: Morse theory exercises

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology, morse-theory

I'm currently learning Morse theory for my masters (with an eye towards K-theory). I'm working through Milnor's Morse Theory however it doesn't have any exercises. From a quick search myself I found Matsumoto's Introduction, which seems to have a small number of relatively easy exercises, and Nicolaescu's Invitation, which as far as I can tell has exercises only for after completing the bulk of the text.

Are there any books or courses which roughly follow Milnor's presentation but have challenging exercises throughout?

Mentioned books:

[An Introduction to Morse Theory (Translations of Mathematical Monographs, Vol. 208), Yukio Matsumoto](https://books.google.ie/books/about/An_Introduction_to_Morse_Theory.html?id=TtKyqozvgIwC&redir_esc=y)

[An Invitation to Morse Theory, Nicolaescu, Liviu](https://books.google.ie/books/about/An_Invitation_to_Morse_Theory.html?id=wJJ0fnq0LPMC&)

[Milnor Morse Theory](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/milnmors.pdf)